# Maximum likelihood estimate of gaussian given rounded values

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Suppose there is a hidden gaussian with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and that $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where the $X_i$ are i.i.d.  If I can only oberve the rounded value of $X_i$, i.e. $Y_i = \lfloor X_i + 1/2 \rfloor$, is there an effective means of computing the maximum likelihood estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

Often rounding doesn't make much difference in the sample mean and variance used to estimate the population mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$ Rounding conventions (such as rounding a 5 in the third place to give an even number in the second when rounding to two places) attempt to decrease bias for the mean.

Here are $n = 150$ observations sampled from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100, \sigma=15),$ along with their sample mean, variance and SD.

```
x = rnorm(150, 100, 15)
mean(x);  var(x);  sd(x)
## 101.3501
## 209.5259
##14.47501
```

Upon rounding to the nearest integer, we find that the sample mean, variance
and SD have not changed much. In 71 of 150 observations, rounding resulted
in a decrease and in the remaining observations an increase.

```
rx = round(x)
mean(rx);  var(rx);  sd(rx)
## 101.3467
## 209.6643
## 14.47979
sum(rx < x)
## 71
```

Trouble can arise if rounding is unreasonably severe. Usually, practitioners
are smart enough not to round so severely that important information is lost.

Here is a case in which rounding is arguably too severe. There is a noticeable
change in the sample mean, variance, and SD, but perhaps not so severe as to
ruin analysis. (Rounding to one decimal place would probably have been OK.)

```
y = rnorm(30, 10, 2)
mean(y);  var(y);  sd(y)
## 10.47787
## 2.773481
## 1.665377
ry = round(y)
mean(ry);  var(ry);  sd(ry)
## 10.53333
## 2.74023
## 1.655364
```

Here are the first six observations, before and after (severe) rounding:

```
head(y)
## 12.501007 10.766729 11.313505  9.660635  9.443169 10.734076
head(ry)
## 13 11 11 10  9 11
```

Here are 95% t CIs for $\mu$.  Original data:

```
95 percent confidence interval:
  9.856012 11.099736
```

Rounded data:

```
95 percent confidence interval:
  9.91521 11.15146
```

---

However, rounding paired data can lead to disaster. If the differences are
relatively small compared with the size of the observations, then rounding
before taking differences can "round away" the true difference.

Perhaps most serious is that carelessly-rounded data often result in ties that
spoil the distribution theory of rank-based nonparametric tests (Wilcoxon,
Kruskal-Wallis, Friedman). Even then, one can sometimes get accurate P-values
by doing a simulated permutation test that imitates the purpose of the
rank-based test. However, this is not usually an issue with data known to be normal.

Finally, is is worthwhile noting that in practice **all** continuous data
must be rounded to some number of decimal places.

---

**Addendum:** (Consequences of absurdly severe rounding, per Comments).

Suppose samples of
size $n = 5$ are taken from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 1, \sigma=.5).$ Below we
plot sample SDs $S$ against sample means $A =\bar X$ for $m = 50,000$ such
samples. At left, the plot illustrates that sample means and SDs for unrounded data are independent; at right, sample means and SDs for observations rounded to integers (thus nonnormal) are no longer independent (even if nearly uncorrelated). [At right, there only 12 uniquely different values of sample means and 13 for sample SDs. So there are many ties, massively overplotted in the figure.]

[image]

R code, in case it's of interest:

```
m = 50000; n = 5
x = rnorm(m*n, 1, .5);  MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)
a = rowMeans(MAT);  s = apply(MAT, 1, sd)
ar = rowMeans(round(MAT));  sr = apply(round(MAT), 1, sd)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(a,s, pch=".", main="Original Data")
  plot(ar, sr, pch=20, main="Severely Rounded")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: @Shashi.  I hope my answer didn't scare you away. Although totally different than mine, your comment/answer is a thoughtful start toward a theoretical approach.

Comment: One problem that I was hoping to get insight into is that the mean and standard deviation for the rounded variable just aren't the same as the unrounded mean and standard deviation.  To give an extreme example, which appears many times in my data, suppose $X \sim \mathcal{N}(.5,.125^2)$.  The rounded variable is basically a 0-1 valued random variable , and it has standard deviation > .5.  No matter how many sample we take, we won't converge to the proper std.  On the other hand, the rounded variable takes values outside of {0,1} so infrequently, that we can tell that the STD is not near .5

Comment: I guess my counter-question is why anyone would want to round such small sample values to _integers._ More appropriate to round to 2 or 3 places, then no difficulty. // Maybe interesting to investigate absurdly severe rounding as a theoretical exercise, but such rounding would never be an issue in responsible  practice. // Severely rounded normal data are no longer normal. By consequence, $\bar X$ and $S$ of severely rounded normal data no longer indep, so "t statistic" of such data no longer t distributed.

Comment: To be very explicit about our problem, we have depth video recorded on a Microsoft Kinect.  We read a paper on compressing the video that suggested binning the depth values in bins of size about equal to (or even 2 or 3 times) the standard deviation of the noise.  This dramatically reduces the delta between frames and from pixel to neighboring pixel, so the videos compress more.  However, we have since learned that there is valuable information in the variance at a pixel, so we are trying to recover it.

Comment: Oh I did not get notified or anything I just saw your comment by accident lol. It did not scare me away , but when I saw the simulations I have reread the question and felt like the question was asking for an approach as yours. I have also got in mind that what I did was so basic that the OP probably did before asking for "effective means of **computing**.." . Nicely done with good discussion of the results and all.